# Mongo Aggregate weighted average with timestamp differences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have datasets of timestamp and price.
Now I want to calculate the average of the price, to calculate

```
[ { price: 23, timestamp: t1}, 
  { price: 24, timestamp: t2},
  { price: 25, timestamp: t3} ]
```

The formulae for my average is :

> (23*(t2-t1) + 24*(t3-t1))/(t3-t1)

To calculate this in for loop take too much time with thousands of datasets.
But in mongo aggregate i am not able to access the previous data set.